# jQuery alert on change text field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, onchange

Html:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="" class="form-control" id="amount">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {*emphasized text*
  $("#amount").change(function() {
     alert( $("#amount").val );

  });
```

It is not alert any value of the given amount field value. It shows me something else like :

```
function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];if(arguments.length)return d=n.isFunction(a)....:null==c?"":c)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) which calls the function instead of `.val` which **is** the function.

```
alert( $("#amount").val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed braces after `val` as it is function you should use **`val()`** instead of `val`

```
$(document).ready(function() {*emphasized text*
  $("#amount").change(function() {
     alert( $("#amount").val() );

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.val()`, use pair of brackets with .val because its a function.

```
alert($("#amount").val());
```